# QtListWidgetItem with Pixmap crashes if to many

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I'm a noob, so sorry if my question feels dumb.
I use Qt Creator to make a kind of image viewer.
I added a QListWidget and added items with a pixmap. So far, so good.
Now I try to read the hole directory and add all 438 images.
The app crashes with this message:

> Cn::Process::NotifyOutOfMemory(). 17:47:36: The program has
>   unexpectedly finished. 17:47:36: The process was ended forcefully.

If I reduce the count to 85. The app opens, but does only show 77 images.

I tried to fix this by changing addItem to addItems but don't know how to get the QListWidgetItem in a QList or on any other way. And than it is the question of this is a solution.

Can someone give me a kick in the right direction?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QDir dir("C:/");
    QStringList items; // String???
    foreach(QFileInfo var, dir.entryInfoList ()){
        if(var.isFile ()){
            //items += // What to do here ??
            ui->listWidget->addItem (new QListWidgetItem(QPixmap(var.absoluteFilePath ()), var.fileName ()));
        }
        ui->listWidget->addItems (items);
    }
}
```

Michael

Comment: how much do the 77 images weigh in total?

Comment: ***The process was ended forcefully.*** OOM killer?? check your dmesg.

Comment: 77 images are 189 MB. Is there a max?

OOM, you mean OutOfMemory? That's what the question is about. dmesg is a linux command. I'm on windows.

Comment: Sorry, I for some reason thought you were on linux. On linux the OS will kill memory hogging tasks via a process called OOM killer.

Comment: ***77 images are 189 MB. Is there a max?*** There is always a maximum however it will depend on how big each image is and if you are developing a 32 or 64 bit application. A 32 bit application will in windows will be limited to 2GB of address space by default regardless of how much virtual memory your computer has.

Comment: @drescherjm ah okay. Thanks for your explanation.
The app is build with MinGW 32bit cause it's the only kit available. Couldn't found out how to use an 64bit kit.
Memory is 8GB and virtual memory is 2GB. 1 image is between 1.5MB and 4MB.
Can it help to use additemS instead of additem? I read that somewhere. But can't get it working.

Comment: Isn't there image file whose size is big?   And all files are images?

Comment: @talent_depeloper No thats not the problem and all files are images. If I create thumbnails than it show all 400+ thumbs. So there is some limit. Can I make it faster anyway?

Comment: No answers, ideas, solutions anymore? How can I use addtimes instead of additem?